# HTML CSS Scrolling Blur

Tags: html, css

Im building a blog for a client, however, I wish to keep the logo and navigation fixed at the top of the page, so in effect the blog content will scroll behind the header. Is it possible for the content to fade out rather than simply hide behind the header? The link to the site in question is here, http://chefpaulcrowe.com/blog/

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Please do not link to your web site. Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: I apologise I will paste the code instead @Diodeus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using css3 liner gradient:

```
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,1));
```

or if you need support for older browsers just put a gradient image on the background:

```
background: url(path/to/the/gradient/image.png)
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qbE3G/)

Comment: Thanks @claustrofob here's the thing, I want the content to fade out behind an image, and as this image is using a responsive background-size: cover; piece of code it will be difficult to use a 'gradient' overlay of the background, is there a way to use an opaque method for the linear-gradent effect do you know? Thanks again